# Border is not drawn around the picture in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding drawing a border around an image uploaded on the HTML. This is my code in HTML:

```css
.imagec {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: black block 2px;
}
```

```html
<img class="imagec" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
```

I do not know why a border is not drawn around my picture:(

In addition, I cannot draw a border around my HTML page too :(

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it as below:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Insted of

```
border: black block 2px;
```

Learn here:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

```css
.imagec{ 
display: block; 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto; 
border: 2px solid black;
}
html{
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img class="imagec" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>


<head>
<style>

.imagec{ display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border: 2px solid black;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<img class="imagec" src="fish.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

I changed your CSS from `border: black block 2px;` to `border: 2px solid black;`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp
`border: black block 2px;` `solid` not `block`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for image:

```
.imagec{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

And, For Your Html page:

```
body{
  margin:0px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```